# Getting error with ngIf in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm using angular and I want to display data from a variable which is in json form
.I'm able to do it for *ngfor but also I want to put a condition where it checks whether msg.who=="Bot".I'm doing that using :

```
<div class="UserWrapper" *ngFor="let msg of msgs" ngIf="msg.who == 'User ">
    <div class=""></div>
        <div class = "speech-bubble1 z-depth-5"><p>{{msg.msg}}</p>
            <p class="timeRight">{{msg.time}}</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I don't know how to use ng if another way but on doing this i'm getting the following error.

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgForOf -> TemplateRef]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgForOf -> TemplateRef]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for TemplateRef!
```

How can I check for the given condition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use **`ngFor`** and **`ngIf`** on the same **`element`**, so replace it with **`ng-container`**,  also few mistakes such as **`*ngIf`** instead of **`ngIf`** and you should use **`===`** when you are checking for the type as well

change your code as follows,

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let msg of msgs">
  <div *ngIf="msg.who === User"  class=""> 
        <div class = "speech-bubble1 z-depth-5"><p>{{msg.msg}}</p>
        <p class="timeRight">{{msg.time}}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: But then how do i check for the condition whether the msg.who is but or user

Comment: @alia In regards to the `===` comment, interestingly, `"1" == 1` will throw a compile error (`Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.`) when in a `.ts` file, however will evaluate as true when used in a template. Therefor you should probably extract type sensitive evaluations into a separate function and reference that instead. @Sajeetharan agree?